# JacksonXML List duplicating tags

Tags: spring-boot, spring-rest, jackson-dataformat-xml

I have this

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "results")
public class GenericResults{
    @JacksonXmlProperty
    private String copyright;
    @JacksonXmlProperty
    private int count;
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "list")
    private List<Result> list;
```

And on the Pojo I have this

```
public class Result {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true, localName = "symbol")
    private String symbol;
    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true, localName = "datatype")
    private String datatype;
    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true, localName = "entitlement")
    private String entitlement;
    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true, localName = "datetime")
    private Long datetime;
```

The result is

```
<results>
<copyright>Copyrights Bla Bla Bla </copyright>
<symbolCount>2</symbolCount>
<list>
<list symbolstring="x" datatype="a" entitlement="r" datetime="1499375390609"/>
<list symbolstring="y" datatype="a" entitlement="r" datetime="1499375390731"/>
</list>
</results>
```

And what i Want to produce is...

```
<results>
<copyright>Copyrights Bla Bla Bla </copyright>
<symbolCount>2</symbolCount>
<list symbolstring="x" datatype="a" entitlement="r" datetime="1499375390609"/>
<list symbolstring="y" datatype="a" entitlement="r" datetime="1499375390731"/>
</results>
```

Someone Can help me?? I tried some other stuff but I was not able to do it... i dont want to have the duplicate tag for list....

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution just use @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
on the list property.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Same effect could be achieved globally (without repeating annotations) if you configure the XmlMapper with `defaultUseWrapper(false)`.